# which is the best programing language to start with?

Tags: c#, javascript, programming-languages

I am a new programmer and i would like to know which is the best language to start with?

i know a little bit of **php** but i want to be careful with the current common languages that are widely used i did a little bit of wordpress too but very limited knowledge and would like to improve my skills in the most commonly used language is **.NET** an option? or **javascript**?

what is the best way to go with for front-end developing?

Thanks

Comment: if you ask me ,use C# and don't ask why ,but i think this question is going to be closed !

Comment: Duplicate, argumentative and subjective. Definitely closing. The answer is: it depends. You can't go wrong starting with the C family; you'll learn a lot than can be used in a lot of other places. C#, C, then C++ is my stock answer.

Comment: Agree ... is going to be closed but I would go for C# and focus on it.

Comment: This is hugely subjective, and has no "right" answer; this is *not* an ideal question for stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The world is moving towards HTML5. If you want to begin with programming web applications start with,

For Web,

1. Scripting languages like,

   1. javascripts / jQuery
2. Styling with,

   1. CSS / CSS3
3. To learn HTML5 http://w3schools.com and
   http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/ would be some great places
   to start!

---

Alternatively if you are choosing between C# (Spelled CSharp) and Java (Not Javascript) I would suggest going for C# currently as of today C# is the best choice for development.

Comment: I would recommend https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn as w3schools has some outdated content (the javascript tutorials use document.write :( )

Comment: thanks for answering VirusZ and peplamb html5 i keep hearing it all the time and how about silverlight actionscript?

Comment: i would suggest not to go with silverlight we had tons of problems and in the recent channel 9 events they haven't mentioned almost anything on silverlight sadly

Answer (score 3):

.NET and c# are a good option. Javascript needed for web client side scripting together with Asp.Net. good luck

Comment: Leave it. HTML5 rocks and pluginless. SL good on windows phone but not for web as does not work from iPhone or Android browsers...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you’re trying to accomplish and where. Each language is somewhat different,  but they still all share some common things as well.

Just pick one that’s the most commonly used in your specific target platform/area and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look for a language that can helps you in any environment and most of situations. In my experience, you'll work with different languages in the future depending on the context. 
But for me, the unique language I have learnt and use every day in many different problems is PERL. 
So that's my recommendation.